# Facebook, how does it use ajax and only update on the users side when called?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

So how do facebook run the newsfeed?

Im trying to create something similar.

From what i have observed, Facebook does not use a $jQuery refresh to get get the updated newsfeed, the comments/likes are separate query's to the database - this makes me think they are separate jQuery loads, but these happen almost instantly?

Can anyone explain how the facebook newsfeed works with comments/likes etc?

Comment: Websockets, probably

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is using react.js for that.
You must read react.js and get good knowledge around react's component and states